# Launching sllauncher in local machine from Citrix

Tags: api, communication, silverlight-5.0, citrix-access-gateway

I have a Silverlight out of browser application which is integrated with 3 party applications. This Silverlight application is installed in Citrix server.

Is there a way to launch the UI of the Silverlight application in local machine while the API has to be in Citrix Server? 
Also the UI in local machine should communicate with API in the Citrix server

Please direct me towards a feasible solution.

Thanks